# How do I get a list of files in a directory in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I've got a directory of CSV files.

I can do:

```
\ls /home/chris/data/
```

which works, producing a list:

```
"AAA.csv"
"AAAU.csv"
"AABA.csv"
```

etc.

However, when I try to assign it, so I can actually do something useful with it:

```
files: \ls /home/chris/data/
```

I'm unable to actually save the list.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `system` keyword, `\` only works if it's the first character on a line:

```
files: system "ls /home/chris/data/"
```

Alternatively, `key` can be used, which I prefer as it's platform-independent with respect to path separators, and the shell command for listing files:

```
key `:/home/chris/data
```